# Find which $_POST variable is empty for IF statement

Tags: php

Is there a way to find which exact `$_POST` variable is empty if I am using several variables in one `if` statement?

Here is a simple example of the `if` statement:

```
if(empty($_POST['Type']) || empty($_POST['Company']) || empty($_POST['InvoiceNumber']) || empty($_POST['Price']) || empty($_POST['Date'])) 
{
    header("Location: ".HOST."invoice_final.php?ErrorFillInfo=???");
}
```

Now what I need to know is if there is some simple solution to know which  `$_POST` variables are empty and then I want replace those variables with "???" and use the GET method to echo exact fields on the next page.

I can do it in a really complicated way where I will separate all five `$_POST` variables into separate `if` statements and call the `header()` function after each `if` statement but this looks too complicated and therefore I am asking if there is not a better way to check for exact `$_POST` variables which are empty.

Answer (score 2):

You can find empty element from array using `array_filter()` and `array_diff()`

```
$non_empty_element = array_filter($_POST);
$empty_element = array_diff($_POST,$non_empty_element);
print_r($empty_element);
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/hXGVU

**Based on the comment of OP**,

> I have on my page 10 inputs fields but only these five fields ($_POST)
>   MUST BE FILLED rest are not MUST HAVE. But then I will get after using
>   array_diff also these inside $empty_element ... Do you understand my
>   point? Is there some way how to filter only these IMPORTANT $_POST THX

**DEMO2** https://3v4l.org/KvaB8

Comment: THX!!! But there is one problem with this solution. If I have some $_POST variables which can be empty because there are not important for correct complet fill then I will get also these $_POSTs inside your $empty_element variables. I will explain it little more. I have on my page 10 inputs fields but only these five fields ($_POST) MUST BE FILLED rest are not MUST HAVE. But then I will get after using array_diff also these inside $empty_element ... Do you understand my point? Is there some way how to filter only these IMPORTANT $_POST THX

Comment: I have one idea.. What about "removing" these not  important $_POST from this $empty_element array variable? Or it is stupid idea?

Comment: @daniel Yes you can do that, I don't think that is stupid idea. No Prob. go ahead

Comment: @daniel Have a look on my **DEMO2** here https://3v4l.org/KvaB8 If it works for as you expected, then don't forgot to accept my answer with GREEN tick :)

Comment: @Sunny I am getting this error if I use your code in DEMO2  Notice: Use of undefined constant ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH - assumed 'ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH' in 

Warning: array_filter() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given

Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in

Warning: array_diff(): Argument #2 is not an array in

Comment: But I was able to solve it with your help and add that unset($empty_element['']); to remove not important $_POSTs. But now when I use $_GET method to pass this information to header("Location: ".HOST."Invoice.php?FillInfo=$empty_element"); I get to my URL FillInfo=0[Company]=&0[InvoiceNumber]=&0[Price]= and when I call for echo $Result = $_GET['FillInfo']; I am getting only first part of the whole array which is 0[Company]= nothing else... I know that there is somtehing wrong with my call because on URL it is "array" but I think I am not calling array correctly